# Cannot apply count() or collecr() on RDD from textfile(Spark)

Tags: pyspark, databricks-community-edition

I am new at Spark and I have Databricks Community Edition account. Right now I'm doing [Lab](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/364056484516092/3299627280456503/8173809219644900/latest.html) and encountered with following error:

```py
!rm README.md* -f 
!wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/carloapp2/SparkPOT/master/README.md

textfile_rdd = sc.textFile("README.md")
textfile_rdd.count()
```

Output:

```py
IllegalArgumentException: Path must be absolute: dbfs:/../dbfs/README.md
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, wget will download your file to `/databricks/driver`
You have to store it in the DataBricks File System (dbfs) in order to be able to read it with the -P option. See [wget manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) for reference.
It also seems that the `!wget` magic creates a file that is not available with the `dbfs:/` path. On Databricks Community, `!wget` leads to a file not found as you mentionned.

You can do the following in a `%sh` cell first:

```sh
%sh
rm README.md* -f 
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/carloapp2/SparkPOT/master/README.md -P /dbfs/downloads/
```

And then in a second python cell, you can access the file throug the Files API (note the path starting with `file:/`

```py
textfile_rdd = sc.textFile("file:/dbfs/downloads/README.md")
textfile_rdd.count()
```

```
--2022-02-11 13:48:19--  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/carloapp2/SparkPOT/master/README.md
Resolving raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)... 185.199.111.133, 185.199.110.133, 185.199.109.133, ...
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|185.199.111.133|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3624 (3.5K) [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘/dbfs/FileStore/README.md.1’

README.md.1         100%[===================>]   3.54K  --.-KB/s    in 0.001s  

2022-02-11 13:48:19 (4.10 MB/s) - ‘/dbfs/FileStore/README.md.1’ saved [3624/3624]

Out[25]: 98
```

The following solution has been tested on a Databricks Community Edition with a 7.1 LTS ML and a 9.1 LTS ML Databricks Runtime.
[image]

Comment: Still get error: 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: dbfs:/FileStore/README.md'

Comment: My previous answer didn't work with Community Edition (with !wget). Try using a %sh instead. I updated the answer with a code tested on Community Edition with a 7.1 LTS ML  and a 9.1 LTS ML Databricks Runtime

Comment: I've solved the issue. Just added additional slash in path "file:///databricks/driver/README.md"

Comment: Much simpler than mine !

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate your time!